# MySQL concatenate two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two MySQL tables with almost the same structure and I want to import the data from one of the tables into the other one. I run Codeigniter and I tried to select all the data from one of the tables and insert into the other but doesn't seem to work very good.

Table structure: url, text, source, img, date

Comment: I know it isn't a literal duplicate, but it's more than close enough to get you there.

If you're still having problems after using INSERT SELECT, then please create a new question which includes the relevant code you're using, and what the error message is.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 FROM table2` I hope this will work.

Comment: @RishiKalal this is what I get when I ran that **Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine**. The two tables have a small difference: one of them have a col named _id_ (with auto-increment) and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to duplicate entries from `table1` into `table2` you can execute the following query:

```
Insert into table1 select * from table2
```

Or you can exclude the id column, as such:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (url,text,source,img,date) SELECT url, text, source, img, date FROM table2
```

In case you are using CodeIgniter 3, you can do it like this

```
 $select_result = $this->db->select('*')->get('table1');
            if ($select_result->num_rows()) {
                $this->db->insert_batch('table2', $select_result->result_array());
            }
```

Comment: Plus 1 for simplicity :)

Comment: This is what I get when I ran that **Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine**. The two tables have a small difference: one of them have a col named _id_ (with auto-increment) and the other doesn't.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: @AamirR already tried that. Same error.

Comment: probably your table storage have an issue, you can reset the auto increment value on that table, as such `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1`